# How to generate master.key on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

How can I get rails to generate a master key? I'm wanting it to decrypt the credentials file in a production environment.

This is how I tried to generate a new key:

```
config$ rm credentials.yml.enc 
config$ EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
File encrypted and saved.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I had RAILS_MASTER_KEY set as an environment variable from testing. Rails was referencing that instead of generating a new key. I unset the environment variable and it's now working.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is looking for a way to generate an encryption key that is exactly 32 characters:

```
$ bundle exec rails secret | cut -c-32
=> 8d000d7e7233facfc8300b9a3fe0421e
```

Then save that to your `.env` as:

```
# Generated by:
# bundle exec rails secret | cut -c-32
# If one is already setup, you may need to ask someone for it.
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=8d000d7e7233facfc8300b9a3fe0421e
```